# Search does not work in my WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, search

the search does not work in my wordpress blog. each time i am searching with a keyword, it turns to zero result, however i know the word exists a thousand times in my blog.

The structure :

1. i have my own theme based on twentyeleven (almost the same).
2. the search is placed into the sidebar, and i use search widget to show it on the front end.
3. the form is in my searchform.php, the code :

   ```
   <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
     <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'ilwebdesign' ); ?></label>
     <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'ilwebdesign' ); ?>" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'ilwebdesign' ); ?>" />
   </form>
   ```
4. the output should be shown on a page which is generated by the search.php file.

I guess the redirection (an url) should have the problem because when i submit the search, the zero result is shown on my error page instead of the search page. The final page where it redirects me : http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/blog/undefined...

Maybe the problem comes from the fact that my wp blog is installed in a subdomaine ? : http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/blog/

Normally i do not have search problem, the system works well because : i installed Search Everything wp plugin to hope that it helps. It installs a trial search in the admin side and when i search with it, it works, it redirects me to the home page (posts list) and even highlights the words. The problem is that this plugin obliged to use the default wp search form and it does not work on the front end, even with this plugin...

Can you please give me ideas what should i do that it works correctly.

Comment: @Gergo Erdosi - hello, how did you do to put the totality of the codes on one line (not breaking it) ? I saw you edited my question, i did exactly the same time, so there was a confusion and also i did not find the way to approve the edition (if i should have been)... sorry

Comment: @Gergo Erdosi - köszönöm !

Comment: Rolled it back to my version. If you want to highlight inline code, use backticks. If you want to highlight a block of code, indent the code by 4 spaces (in this case 8 spaces were needed because of the list). See this page for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like an issue caused from rewrite rules or the subdomain hosting.

That /undefined page is actually a 404 page (check out, article tag has classes "post error404 not-found").

I tried appending "?s=Blogger" to your wp blog url an it shows results normally.

I'm almost sure it depends on one of the many javascript libraries loaded, **maybe the preloader**, and I guess the culprit js has some issue with the equal character in the search results url.

On a side note, looks like you are loading jquery twice, 1.11 in the <head> and 1.10.2. at the bottom.

I might suggest adding this rule to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.+)\&
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [R,L]
```

(from comments on http://wpengineer.com/2258/change-the-search-url-of-wordpress/ )

This rewrites an url like *webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/blog/?s=Blogger* into *webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/blog/search/Blogger* , and might fix the issue if I'm right about the preloader.

If it doesn't work, it might help trying to disable one by one the plugins used -to get rid of their sideloaded scripts- and reload the homepage until the search works.

If it doesn't work, probably it's not an issue related to plugins but to the theme loaded scripts.

Comment: thank ! Concerning jquery, once i use mine and i put the link into the footer, and once it is WP jquery which is added automatically into the header. As far as i remember (or i did it in another websire ???) i deleted once the wp jquery, if it came back, maybe it happened at wp update. the problem is that wp adds it to the header when i want it to the footer, i read that it is better for the performance... 
Concerning .htaccess, i added your line but nothing happens, is there a specific location to place it ? i added it at the bottom of the existing codes...

Comment: thanks again ! i saw you edited your answer... i tried with the completred code of .htaccess, it does not work yet... i must go now but i will try later not to use the search by the search widget but by the get_searchform code directly, maybe it will help, and i will let you know !